# Accessing Macbook Webcam on Ubuntu via VMWare Fusion

Tags: ubuntu, webcam, vmware-fusion, opencv

I am writing a program in C++ using opencv. I am working on Ubuntu via VMWare Fusion.

When I run my program, it seems the integrated webcam on my Mac is not recognized so I get the error message I coded when not able to access a camera footage. Does anyone have any experience with this and can give me some suggestions.

Comment: I have some experience with Windows and Ubuntu only, both hosts and guests, and Virtualbox. Usually USB connected devices need to be passed to the guest via a function menu.

Comment: sorry, does this also apply to integrated webcams. I have na USB connected webcam

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the answer yet:

Power down virtual machine. 
From the "Virtual Machine" menu, go to settings.

Then, double check the advanced settings in the USB/Bluetooth menu and make sure they are at least USB2 compatible.

Then, again in the settings menu, click on "add device" and in the following dialog: 
[image: settings dialog add device]
select camera here and you should be going.

Answer (score 0):

Certain cameras may not work well with virtual USB camera. Perform these steps to enable pass through of cameras in to virtual machine:

1. Ensure to shutdown all virtual machines and quit VMware Fusion if
   its running.
2. Open Terminal ( /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app)
3. Run this command to change the current location.

   ```
   cd ~/Library/Preferences/VMware\ Fusion/
   ```
4. Open the preferences file using vi or nano editors in terminal

   ```
   nano preferences
   ```
5. Add this parameter at the end of the file:

   ```
   vusbcamera.passthrough = "TRUE"
   ```
6. Save and close the preferences file.
7. Launch VMware Fusion and startup your virtual machine.
8. Important: Remove all existing camera devices.
9. Click Virtual Machine menu > USB and Bluetooth Setting
10. Select the Camera you want from the list to connect it to the virtual machine.